# Sitecore 9 Reporting Database records are updating very slow

Tags: experience-analytics, processing

**Problem:** Sitecore analytics dashboard is updating very slow around (12 days delay) and old records are updating very slow (around 50 records per hours), on the dashboard

**Analysis So Far:** Records are updating in the SQL server collection database, also records are updating into the processing pool table, however not updating into the reporting database means slowing updating.

**Checked the server** - everything is fine (16 GB ram with 8 cores) memory utilization is only 30%

Using Sitecore 9 update 1

Comment: I am facing similar issue.
did you found any resolution for this?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing the same issue, it is a known issue.

Please see the link https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/224364 regarding the same.